# Docker does not give source deb repositories, is it okay?

Tags: docker

The docker sources are reachable on various places (mainly, GitHub).

There are also many package repositories to download docker, these are hosted mainly by themselves.

However, they have no source deb repos (deb-src...). It seems, their debian packages are binary-only and so is it.

More likely, this source repo probably exists, but it is not public.

Is it okay? Are they allowed to do that?

Comment: What's the license? What does it say? Even the GPL doesn't require that source code be given, only that it be made available on request.

Comment: @curiousdannii Wiki says the license is Apache-2. I don't know, what it says. I could download it, but I am not an U.S. lawyer. I think "is practice X okay" should be very on-topic here.

Comment: Even the GPL does not require that sources be made in a particular packaging format such as deb repos. This is going to be very distribution specific. The most distribution neutral way is probably a tarball or zip file with sources and build scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is entirely okay to distribute only binaries of Docker (or any other project licensed under the Apache License version 2).

The Apache license version 2 has the following text regarding distribution:

> **4. Redistribution.** You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and in Source or Object form, provided that You meet the following conditions:
>
> 1. You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License; and
> 2. You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating that You changed the files; and
> 3. You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices from the Source form of the Work, excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works; and
> 4. If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution, then any Derivative Works that You distribute must include a readable copy of the attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file, excluding those notices that do not pertain to any part of the Derivative Works, in at least one of the following places: within a NOTICE text file distributed as part of the Derivative Works; within the Source form or documentation, if provided along with the Derivative Works; or, within a display generated by the Derivative Works, if and wherever such third-party notices normally appear. The contents of the NOTICE file are for informational purposes only and do not modify the License. You may add Your own attribution notices within Derivative Works that You distribute, alongside or as an addendum to the NOTICE text from the Work, provided that such additional attribution notices cannot be construed as modifying the License.
>
> You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use, reproduction, or distribution of Your modifications, or for any such Derivative Works as a whole, provided Your use, reproduction, and distribution of the Work otherwise complies with the conditions stated in this License.

None of the four requirements that you must meet mentions the distribution of the Source form when you distribute the Object form. This means that it is entirely legal to distribute only the Object form, which means only the binaries.